# How to implement a simplified regex matcher?

Tags: python, regex

As part of an assignment (yes, I said it; as a consequence, we are not allowed to `import re` even to test), I have implemented a way of parsing a certain regular expression format into a tree `r`, where:

- `r.symbol` is the type of node
  (`e` = ε, `0` or `1` = terminals, `.` = sequence, `|` and `*` are obvious)
- `r.children` is the list of `(0, 1, 2)` child nodes.

The only characters that can be matched by this format are `0`, `1` so those are also the only possible terminals.

```
def match(r, s):
    """
    Return True iff the list of characters `s' matches the
    regular expression stored in `r'.
    """
    if r.symbol == 'e':
        return True
    elif r.symbol in '01':
        return r.symbol == s.pop(0) if len(s) > 0 else False
    elif r.symbol == '.':
        return match(r.children[0], s) and match(r.children[1], s)
    elif r.symbol == '|':
        sl, sr = s.copy(), s.copy()
        kl, kr = match(r.children[0], sl), match(r.children[1], sr)
        if kl or kr:
            s = (sl if kl else sr) if kl != kr else \
                (sl if len(sl) < len(sr) else sr)
            return True
        return False
    elif r.symbol == '*':
        while match(r.children[0], s):
            pass
        return True
```

My implementation works by taking a list of characters and popping characters from the left side one at a time if they match the regex. I've matched most of my test cases so far, but there are specific kinds of regexes on which it fails. I know I'm not done yet, so here are my questions:

1. I can't seem to implement the Kleene star `*` correctly. It just doesn't look like doing a `while` loop is the best way to do this.
2. How does the `|` alternative operator actually work? I currently have it implemented such that if both match, then it returns the longer match.

Comment: Look into the module [sre_parse.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e8cead08c556/Lib/sre_parse.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a finite state machine because it should be fairly easy to do with just basic operations.

Here is an article that shows how to implements basic regex operations as a NFA:

[Regular expressions](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to do it directly, but then it is hard to argue about correctness.
The common approach is to first translate a regex to a finite state machine (in whatever representation you like), then simulate input on that finite state machine.

Comment: This is a really simple implementation of regexes, just need to match `0`, `1` so I think writing FSMs is too much, for this purpose at least. I would be happy to write my own regex library if I needed to.